# Origin in Löve program window?

Tags: lua, love2d

Where is (0,0) in the Löve program window?

Or, simply put, what quadrant of the coordinate plane is the game window set in?

Comment: Pretty easy to test for yourself; draw a circle centered at 0,0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics.draw): "The origin is by default located at the *top left corner* of Image and Canvas.".

Comment: This link has a diagram and explicitly  mentions screen coordinate system https://love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics